# solr - defined stored="true" and required="true" and the fields are not displayed in * search

Tags: solr, solr4

I do a simple query as follows

```
http://....:8983/solr/vault/select?q=*:*
```

I dont see all the fields that I declared as stored="true" and required="true"

for insance, i have defined the following filed which is not displayed in the results:

```
<field name="Comments" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

(I can see it in

```
 http://...:8983/solr/#/vault/schema
```

and I see it weas loaded in the sql profiler)

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields to be displayed are defined by 'fl' parameter and can be configured against the SearchHandler in solrconfig.xml.
If you want to see the field values after hitting the URL, append '&fl=*' to the URL.

```
http://....:8983/solr/vault/select?q=*:*&fl=*
```

If you want to specify all fields by default, update solrconfig.xml file. Refer to sample config file at [example solr config](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml)

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="df">text</str>
   <str name="fl">*,score</str>  <!-- field entry added-->
 </lst>
```

Comment: Thanks. I do have this line. <str name="df">Comments</str>.  and even if I query with fl=comments or fl=* i dont see it

Comment: check whether the content is actually indexed against that field using Luke

Answer (score 0):

Can you see any of the data that you have loaded? If not, make sure you have committed your updates to the index.

You can issue a hard commit via `http://....:8983/solr/value/update?commit=true`